# How to fix input validation error on user input?

Tags: android, validation, if-statement

I have added a basic calculation to this class based on three user inputs.

But I have found that if a user enters zero values the application crashes,which I understand is a result of the calculation being past null values.

So I tried to remedy this by adding the following simple validation.I'm asking if there is a step I'm missing here that it's still crashing? Is there an alternate way of fixing this?

```
            if (offsetLength.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            }

            if (offsetDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            }
            if (ductDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 
            }
```

The logcat errors for reference:  http://pastebin.com/REZ4PeRs

Comment: Does the getText() method return a String or null? Code could text for null before testing the length.

Comment: getText() is a stock method in Java.I'm not sure what you mean? The problem I'm having i that the app is crashing even though I have added a check for zero input..Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try x.getText().length()!= 0 rather than >.